# BadRequest in WebHook on Azure Kudu Console

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks, kudu

I want to call a Azure function after PostDeployment. So I have a created a HttpTriggerCsharp Azure function.

I have done the following:-

- Go to Kudu console
- Tools
- Web hooks
- Add HttpTriggerCsharp Azure
  function URL with PostDeployment option.
- I am using Git-hub for
  deployment. I am doing push now.
- HttpTriggerCsharp Azure function is
  called and executed. But I see Status and Reason of the Web hook as
  **Bad Request**. Refer [image]

  Why I am Status and Reason as "Bad Request"? What is the issue here?

Comment: Could you share your function implementation?

Comment: @Mikhail It is working now. I  have removed the code which relates to request body line ( dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();).

Comment: Would you close the question or edit/answer it, whatever makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the code which relates to request body ( dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync();).

Now my code is working now.